# Using a std::set in a class?

Tags: c++, syntax

I am trying to combine using a std::set and a class, like this:

```
#include <set>

class cmdline
{
    public:
        cmdline();
        ~cmdline();

    private:
        set<int> flags; // this is line 14
};
```

but, it doesn't like the set flags; part:

```
cmdline.hpp:14: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'set' with no type
cmdline.hpp:14: error: expected ';' before '<' token
make: *** [cmdline.o] Error 1
```

As far as I can see, I gave a type (of int). Do you write the "set variable" line differently, or is it not allowed there?

Comment: Bonus points for actually marking with a comment which line the errors refer to. Wish more people did that :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `std::set`; `set` is in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You mean `std::set`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the std:: namespace (for all STL/SL classes).

```
 std::set< int > myset;
```

or

```
 using namespace std; // don't do this in a header - prefer using this in a function code only if necessary
```